# WebRTC iOS: Record Remote Audio stream using WebRTC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webrtc

I am working on an audio streaming application with recording functionality for a receiver.

I got stuck at the point where the user want to record audio stream on the receiver side.

Below is my code
***Initialisation***

```
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
var recordingFile: AVAudioFile?
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
var isRecording: Bool = false
```

***Initialise AudioEngine***

```
func initializeAudioEngine() {

        let input = self.engine.inputNode
        let format = input.inputFormat(forBus: 0)

        self.engine.attach(self.player)
        let mainMixerNode = self.engine.mainMixerNode
        self.engine.connect(input, to:mainMixerNode, format: format)
        self.engine.prepare()

        do {
            try self.engine.start()
            self.startRecording()
        } catch (let error) {
            print("START FAILED", error)
        }
    }
```

***Start Recording***

```
func startRecording() {

        self.createRecordingFile()

        self.engine.mainMixerNode.installTap(onBus: 0,
                                         bufferSize: 1024,
                                         format: self.engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
            do {
                self.isRecording = true
                try self.recordingFile?.write(from: buffer)
            } catch (let error) {
                print("RECORD ERROR", error);
            }
            return
        }
    }
```

***Create Buffer***

```
private func createBuffer(forFileNamed fileName: String) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
        var res: AVAudioPCMBuffer?

        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "caf") {
            do {
                let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)
                res = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: file.processingFormat, frameCapacity:AVAudioFrameCount(file.length))
                if let _ = res {
                    do {
                        try file.read(into: res!)
                    } catch (let error) {
                        print("ERROR read file", error)
                    }
                }
            } catch (let error) {
                print("ERROR file creation", error)
            }
        }
        return res
    }
```

***Stop Recording***

```
func stopRecording() {
   self.engine.mainMixerNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
}
```

I am trying to record using earphone, but It's not working

Comment: WebRTC don't provide any option of recording on the receiving side.

Comment: Please share with us what you've tried and what is not working. Also consider reformulating your question. "Can anyone help?" is not the [right way of asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @normanius I tried with AVAudioEngine to record voice from earphone, but It's not working

Answer (score 0):

Its will work because once you setup

```
let audiosession = AVAudioSession()
```

As **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord** and set

```
audiosession.setActive(true)
```

It will start recording whichever audio dump to device.

Answer (score -2):

WebRTC does not have any Internal API to start or stop recording. 
We can try using **AVAudioSession** instead.

**First setUp Audio session**

```
func setUPAudioSession() -> Bool {
      let audiosession = AVAudioSession()
      do {
        try audiosession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
      } catch(let error) {
         print("--> \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
     do {
        try audiosession.setActive(true)
      } catch (let error) {
        print("--> \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
        return audiosession.isInputAvailable;
}
```

**After setUp the audio session now start recording as below**

```
func startRecording() -> Bool {
      var settings: [String: Any]  = [String: String]()
          settings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
          settings[AVSampleRateKey] = 8000.0
          settings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 1
          settings[AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey] = 16
          settings[AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey] = false
          settings[AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey] = false
          settings[AVAudioQualityMax] = AVEncoderAudioQualityKey
    //Create device directory where recorded file will be save   automatically
           let searchPaths: [String] =               NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .allDomainsMask, true)
         let documentPath_ = searchPaths.first
         let pathToSave = "\(documentPath_)/\(dateString)"
         let url: URL = URL(pathToSave)
         recorder = try? AVAudioRecorder(url: url, settings: settings)
         // Initialize degate, metering, etc.
         recorder.delegate = self;
         recorder.meteringEnabled = true;
         recorder?.prepareToRecord()
         if let recordIs = recorder {
             return recordIs.record()
         }
         return false
  }
```

**Play recorded file**

```
func playrecodingFile() {
    //Get the path of recorded file saved in previous method
    let searchPaths: [String] =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .allDomainsMask, true)
     let documentPath_ = searchPaths.first
     let fileManager = FileManager.default
     let arrayListOfRecordSound: [String]
      if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: recordingFolder()) {
          let arrayListOfRecordSound = try?     fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentPath_)
      }
  let selectedSound = "\(documentPath_)/\(arrayListOfRecordSound.first)"
  let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: selectedSound)
  let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
      player?.delegate = self;
      try?  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
      player?.prepareToPlay()
      player?.play()
}
```

**Stop recording**

```
func stopRecording() {
   recorder?.stop()
 }
```

**pauseRecording**

```
func pauseRecording() {
    recorder?.pause()
}
```

**Stop recording**

```
func stopRecording() {
    recorder?.stop()
}
```

Comment: This won't work because AVAudioRecorder record what we speak, not what we are listening, I want to record what we listening from server end

Comment: Its will work because once you setup
    let audiosession = AVAudioSession()
As **AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord** and set 
    audiosession.setActive(true)
It will start recording whichever audio dump to device.

Comment: It record audio, what we speak on speaker, not from earphone, FYI: AVAudioSession become RTCAVAudioSession in WebRTC, So, AudioSession is already there

Comment: @Daljeet: Thank you it works for me. I can able to record the remote stream as well as the local audio-video stream.

Comment: Great @Hardik1344

Comment: @Hardik1344 I have done the same but i can hear the recoded voice what  what we speak its recorded and its not recording RTCAVAudioSession in WebRTC.If you can elaborate more

Comment: @Hardik1344 I am facing a similar issue. I'm trying to catch remote audio buffer and convert it to AVAudioPCMBuffer to perform analysis on it. No problem to record local audio when it's about remote it's not working.